# How to submit an iOS app to the App Store without changing the Bundle Identifier

Tags: ios, app-store, bundle-identifier

I was developing an iOS app for a few months and now my client wants to publish the app to his developer account. In the development process we were using Testflight to test it and I've put it on our developer account.

The situation right now look like this: we were using Firebase and Push notifications so if I change the bundle identifier for client submission it will not work properly.

What should I do to upload an app with the same bundle identifier from another developer account? Should I delete App ID from our account and then try to make certificate on the client account?

Comment: bundle id is one time register after not possible to submit same application in app store.

or if you try to delete app id and then may it's work.

Comment: no way to delete the app

Comment: How about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8026686/revisions ?
If I delete the App ID like they say, will I be able to upload the app with the same bundle identifier from another account?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **NO**.

You cannot change the bundle ID. If you try to delete the bundle id from developer portal it will throw an error saying that the bundle id is in use.

If you try to delete the app from itunesconnect, there is no option to delete (yes! its true).

There are 2 options here:

1) Change the bundle id of the app and re-register and upload a new build to clients account, then you have to change the push notification and firebase configuration.

2) Transfer the app: In this you have to make the app live from your account and then transfer it to your client's account. Yes you have to make the app live to transfer the app, you cannot transfer the app while the status is preparing to submit. Then you can keep the bundle id same. More details [here](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deved688524f)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I as knew we can transfer the app from one account to another account, please check the below link...

https://support.appmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000012284-Transfer-your-app-to-another-iOS-Developer-Account